# Can creating partition on a Hard disk, affect the data

Tags: diskpart, disk-management

I have Accidentally erased whole disk of my laptop, now Linux mint is running the partition of the disk is like this (.      /Dev/sda1 ext4  927GB, /Dev/sda2   extended 3.92 GB,  /Dev/sda5 Linux-swap 3.93GB. **Now my question is if I create an extra partition on my disk than is it going to affect my data which I want to recover**

Comment: In case you didn't write any data on new partition you could still recover the lost data. instruction to recover re-partitioned hard drive: http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-repartitioned-drives.htm

Comment: If you already installed an OS on the disk, you already overwrote the data you want to recover, based on the information you provided it's already too late to recovery your data.

Comment: But the current OS is Linux Mint, it has hardly acquired 5 to 6 GB out of 931GB. Apart from that, I haven't wrote anything.

Answer (score 1):

NEVER write data to a drive you want to recover data from, as you'll very likely overwrite the data you're trying to restore (causing it to be un-restorable).